# How to add Custom folder to font cache list

Tags: fonts

Hi I know that we can add ~/.fonts folder and update font cache using fc-cache -fv command. 
Is there any way we can add a custom folder say : /home/myuser/myfolder/myos/myfont to the font cache ?

Thanks in advance